# How to Peek-Lock Message and not Receive and Delete on Azure Service Bus Topic using REST Client

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, rest-client

At Microsfot Docs I don't saw the diference from Receive and Delete Message from Peek-Lock Message. The Request is the same.

I tried the request using Postman. How to use Peek and how to use Delete? See the documentation link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/receive-and-delete-message-destructive-read

I need to use Peek, i want keep the message for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you closely look at the HTTP Request methods, for `Peek Lock` the request method is `Post` while for `Receive and Delete` it is `Delete`.

If you want to `Peek Lock` a message, you will need to use `HTTP POST` method.

However, please keep in mind that `Peek Lock` method dequeues a message from the queue and it will remain invisible to other callers for certain duration. Furthermore after a message has been dequeued a certain number of times, it will be dead lettered.

Unfortunately simple peeking at a message (i.e. fetching a message without dequeuing it) is not possible with REST API (HTTP Protocol). You will need to use `AMQP` protocol to do so.